# "Transition morphism" of fiber bundle

Tags: category-theory, definition, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

I want categorical approach to the notion "transition functions of fiber bundle".
I have found the page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+bundle#definitions in nLab.

According to this page, Fiber bundle has "transition morphisms"$g_{\alpha,\beta}$　as transition functions.
But the difinition of $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ is omitted as a phrase (diagram to come) in the page.

How do we define the "transition morphisms" $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ $??$
Please give me opinions $!!$

Comment: I've added a couple diagrams to that page: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+bundle#TransitionMorphisms. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you !!! I'll be able to understand that.